# Python Django website not showing on Ubuntu like on Windows

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, font-awesome, bootstrap-5

I run into a problem without understanding where it could come from.
I have the same website in Django 3.0.8 under environment which works on one side on a PC with windows 10:

[image: preview on Windows]

On the other side, on an old PC with Xubuntu 20.04:

[image: preview on Xubuntu]

Everything is the same: code, files, environments, version of python (3.8). However, the Xubuntu version doesn't perform well as you can see.

Do you have any idea what could be blocking? I have the impression that Bootstrap and FontAwesomeIcon are not working correctly.

.

**EDIT :** This is the code of the page.html

```html
    {% load i18n %}
    {% load static %}
    {% load bootstrap5 %}
    
    {% get_current_language as language_code %}
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="{{ language_code }}">
    <head>
    
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="description" content="Une vie électrique sans barrière.">
        <meta name="author" content="Pierre TREMELO">
    
        <link rel="icon" href="{% static 'favicon.ico' %}">
    
        <title>ElyanDeal</title>
    
        <link href="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
        
        <!-- CUSTOMING -->
        <link href="{% static 'css/fontawesome.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
    <img src="{% static 'accounts/fond_accueil.jpg' %}" class="superbg" />
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark static-top">
    
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
            <i class="fas fa-home"></i> {% trans 'Home' %}
        </a>
    
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            {% trans 'Mon compte' %}
                        </a>
                        
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'accounts:change_profile' %}?next={{ request.path }}">
                                {% trans 'Profil' %}
                            </a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'accounts:change_password' %}">
                                {% trans 'Mot de passe' %}
                            </a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'accounts:change_email' %}">
                                {% trans 'Email' %}
                            </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'accounts:log_out' %}">
                                {% trans 'Déconnexion' %}
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                {% else %}
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'accounts:log_in' %}">{% trans 'Connexion' %}</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'accounts:sign_up' %}">{% trans 'Créer un compte' %}</a>
                    </li>
                {% endif %}
            </ul>
    
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'change_language' %}">{{ language_code|upper }}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    
    </nav>
    
    <div class="container-fluid mt-3">
    
        {% bootstrap_messages %}
    
        {% block content %}
            No content.
        {% endblock %}
    
    </div>
    
    <script src="{% static 'vendor/jquery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'vendor/popper/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    
    <script src="{% static 'js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js' %}"></script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

And this one for the content of the `{% block content %}` :

```html
{% extends 'layouts/default/page.html' %}

{% load i18n %}
{% load static %}
{% load bootstrap5 %}

{% block content %}

<div class="center-etroit" style="background-color:transparent; max-width:500px;">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h4>{% trans 'Connexion' %}</h4>
        </div>
        
        <div class="card-body">
        
            <form method="post">

                {% csrf_token %}
                {% bootstrap_form form %}

                <button class="btn btn-primary">{% trans 'Connexion' %}</button>

            </form>

            <hr>

            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="{% url 'accounts:restore_password' %}">{% trans 'Mot de passe oublié ?' %}</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="{% url 'accounts:remind_username' %}">{% trans 'Identifiant oublié ?' %}</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="{% url 'accounts:resend_activation_code' %}">{% trans "Renvoyer le code d'activation" %}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I can't figure out the difference between the two pictures. So can you please explain what you are getting in windows, which is missing in Ubuntu?

Comment: On window is working. There are the house logo before the word "Accueil". There are not the same space between the different lines. and worst of all (but which is not seen in the image), the navbar doesn't work : if I click on, anything happen.

Comment: Could it be from javascript or Jquery? But how to check it?

Comment: It's rather not about the code itself (Django) but about how do you open these pages. Do you use the same browser (which versions)? Do you run that page locally and open that in localhost?

Comment: And please open the dev console and see what's there.

Comment: Hi @AdamTokarski and thank you. I carried out two tests: I first opened both sites on the Windows PC (one directly locally, the other via the HTTP server that I created on the Xubuntu PC) with exactly the same browser. Secondly I opened locally on the Xubuntu PC. I had the same result each time (photo above). Upon opening the browser dev console, I noticed that the CSS displayed is not the same. How is it possible whereas the files are exactly the same (copied from one PC to another) ?!

Comment: PS : I use Chrome on Windows PC and Firefox on Xubuntu PC

Comment: Is it possible that I incorrectly installed or configured Python, Django or something else do you think ? Like static folder or asset folder maybe ?

Comment: I bet that it's not about the Python or Django themselves. Yes, it may be that you have misconfigured some assets so you don't see the icons, etc. But in such case most likely you would see either some errors in logs on Django side or some errors in browsers dev console. Start with the latter - observe the dev console in both tabs - console and network with checked "preserve logs" (at least on chrome). Open that console and refresh the page. Is there something in red?

Comment: "Upon opening the browser dev console, I noticed that the CSS displayed is not the same" - what exactly does it mean? How did it differ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the issu! I had installed `'django-fontawesome-5'` instead of `'fontawesome-free'` in my virtual environment. Now that I have reinstalled the correct package, the appearance is fixed!